# Вывод 2-х мерного массива по строчно

Tags: java

Как 2-х мерный массив по столбцам то есть если 3х3 тогда <br>
0 0 0<br>
0 0 0<br>
0 0 0<br>
А у меня выводит вот так:<br>
0<br>
0<br>
0<br>
0<br>
0<br>
0<br>
0<br>
0<br>
0<br>
<br>

```
int[][] map = new int[5][5];

                for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                        map[i][j] += 0;
                        System.out.println(map[i][j]);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: у меня нет слов.

Comment: простите, а что это за хитрое колдунство?

    map[i][j] += 0

Comment: 0 + 0 == 0

Comment: Заполнил массив просто нулями.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Включаем голову. `println` выводит текст и делает перевод строки.
Нужно выполнять перевод строки только во внешнем цикле.

```
int[][] map = new int[5][5];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    map[i][j] += 0;
    System.out.print(map[i][j]);
    System.out.print(" ");
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: как я сразу не додумался, спасибо =) Только начал учить язык на задачах.